Pydantic ConfigDict(use_enum_values=True) has no effect when providing default value. How can I provide default values?
The following is a simplified example.
I need to configure ConfigDict(use_enum_values=True) as the code performs model_dump(), and I want to get rid of raw enum values for the purpose of later serialization.
How can A provide a default value for A.x, so that model_dump() outputs the enum value and not the enum itself?
Bonus: Is there any way for A to initilize A.x itself and make it impossible for users to set it? After all, default values can be overriden
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class X(Enum):
   x = "X"
   y = "Y"
   z = "Z"

class A(BaseModel):
   model_config = ConfigDict(use_enum_values=True, frozen=True)
   x: X = X.x

>>> A()
A(x=<X.x: 'X'>)

>>> A(x=X.x)
A(x='X')


I've been debugging an cryptic import issue between Airflow and Pydantic. The issue was arizing at the stage of XCom generation. Your question pointed me towards a fix. The issue was similarly due to an enum attribute with a default value.

You can use the validate_default config option to validate the default values as well. See:
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class X(Enum):
    x = "X"
    y = "Y"
    z = "Z"

class A(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        use_enum_values=True,
        frozen=True,
        validate_default=True,
    )
    x: X = X.x

Which now outputs:
>>> A()
A(x='X')

I hope this helps!
